# Include JavaScript in Ruby (on Rails)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't quite understand how Rails includes JavaScript files.
Google and the following documentations didn't solve my problem:
http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

I understand that Rails uses manifest-files (e.g. applications.js) to pack every included JavaScript file into one big file (performance reasons, etc.).

In application.html.erb you need to include this manifest, like

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

I added a JavaScript file to **/app/assets/** (e.g. my_javascript.js).
So, if I look at the Source-Code, I can find

```
<script src="/assets/application.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and if I open the file, the content of my_javascript.js is rendered in the application.js file.

My Problem: The function is not working. But if I directly include the my_javascript.js in the application.html.erb, like

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "my_javascript" %>
```

it is working! Of course, it renders a second script-tag, like:

```
<script src="/assets/my_javascript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So finally, why does the function work if I include it in specific and not if I use the manifest (how it's supposed to)? Do I need to consider something special about the Assets-Pipeline?
My manifest includes

```
//= require_tree .
```

but I even tried it with

```
//= require my_javascript
```

I'm on Rails 3.2.3 with Ruby 1.9.3.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this problem appear in development env or in production?

Comment: When you say, *the content of my_javascript.js is rendered in the application.js file* are there other things in the `application.js` file as well? When it's all together in that file, are any javascript syntax errors introduced? A small error could cause it to ignore the entire script.

Comment: Are both `<script>` tags generated by each method placed in the same point at your html? It seems to me like an issue of your Javascript reading or manipulating some element in your DOM - in which case it will only work if it is included after that element is created.

Comment: @hedgesky: It happen in development and production
@mbratch: I just deleted everything in the the `application.js` and just included `my_javascript.js` still the same

Comment: OK, I need to take that back. If I exclude everything else of the js. file it is working!
It's not working if I include controls.js, dragdrop.js, effects.js or rails.js (which are default-rails javascrpits I think)
one of my includes are `jquery-1.9.1` `jquery-ui-1.10.3`. Might this cause a conflict?

Comment: You need to look at your `application.js` very carefully after including your new script from `my_javascript.js` to make sure you aren't introducing a syntax error. Without details on the file contents themselves, it's difficult for us to solve here.

Comment: You said that you added the javascript file to **app/assets/**, but with the asset pipeline, you should add it to **app/assets/javascripts/** instead.

Comment: @jvperrin: I actually added it to app/assets/javascripts/, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @mbratch: you're probably right. I'll check the syntax of the JavaScript. It seems it is probably more an issue of the JavaScript Code, than any Rails problem.
Thanks guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting in `Application` Layout

`<%= yield :head %>` in the between `head` tags.